# Shall, I implement Repository, Unit of Work for EF6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

Since MSDN says about [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
> Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
> and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
> as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.

Is it not redundant to implement these two (Unit of Work & Repository) when using EF5+?

Can somebody shed more light on this subject?

I intend to build an MVC based application using SQL server and after reading a lot about data access techniques with unit testability, I am kind of lost with the above info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the complexity of your project and its requirements. For instance, these two questions might help your decision making:

1. Will you use any other data sources besides EF that must work along it?
2. How likely it is that you swap EF for a different ORM or data source in the future?

If you can't foresee changes or you don't need to work with more than just EF then it's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: The trouble is really minimal with a generic repository.

Comment: @jnovo: For both the questions, my answer is "No". My primal concern is (easy) test-ability of the entire application!

Comment: @SamLeach well, again I think it depends on the project. Far too many times people start using a lot of boilerplate for really small stuff. Arguably, there is little point in using generic repos if you are not going to inject the dependencies, etc. Besides, there are disadvantages that must be weighted in such as losing EF features by not using it directly.

Comment: @jnovo, +1 you can loose features if you do not expose them.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Generic repository so you can mock it in your tests more easily than mocking Entity Framework's context directly. But, yes, EF 5+ does implement these patterns as MSDN states.

It's a layer of abstraction. The repository pattern is a collection of objects and a thing to get a collection of objects. Entity Framework knows HOW to get that collection of objects, the repository does not know HOW.

Entity Framework has a lot features that you potentially loose by wrapping it in a repository or a thinner service. If you practise TDD coding against your own classes is often more comfortable than mocking third-party code.

[Ayende has a blog post about this.](http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer)

Comment: Ayende's blog triggered this question, but I actually wanted to ensure that, has somebody tested the waters (of using raw EF, without a wrapper around) with unit testing around it?

Comment: @Nauman I wouldn't because generally testing a third-party library is a pain. EF might not be a pain but I generally stay away from it, you could settle for a thin service around it instead of a repository.

Comment: Do you have a working sample of a generic repository implementation? Or can you point me to a resource, which can provide that?

Comment: There are quite a few examples around. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc and search /search?q=ef+generic+repository